# GE brand new front load washer trips breaker every single time within 5 mins (model GFW850SSNWW)

Tags: circuit-breaker, washer

GE brand new front load washer trips breaker every single time within 5 mins (model GFW850SSNWW). Connected to a GFCI protected outlet (does not have TEST/ RESET buttons on it) and GFCI breaker (SWD brand) since it's in the utility room. Washer works when plugged to a standard  Can you please suggest what could we do?

Comment: This question gets posted quite a bit - Have you looked at any of the other questions using the [search](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=washer+GFCI) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I figure out why my washing machine is tripping the GFCI receptacle?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16434/how-can-i-figure-out-why-my-washing-machine-is-tripping-the-gfci-receptacle)

Comment: Wait, you have a GFCI recep fed from a GFCI breaker?  Belt and suspenders?  I would get rid of one of them.  Put it on a circuit that has no GFCI protection at all.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Yes the outlet states GFCI protection enabled and the electrician said the breaker is GFCI too. When I plug the washer to  standard plus (in the hallway; not in the laundry room), it works just fine

Comment: Oh, well a plain outlet with a sticker is GFCI protected, but it's not a GFCI outlet itself.  That's a perfectly fine way to wire that, the sticker is just saying the circuit is protected.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Do you recommend just flipping the GFCI protected outlet for a standard outlet since the Breaker is GFCI?

Comment: @user117954, does the outlet have TEST and RESET buttons on it?  If not, it isn't a GFCI outlet.  The breaker is providing the protection.  If it is, then you don't need it since you have the breaker.

Comment: Here's what's freaking me out. Normally when a GFCI trip happens, it trips *all* the GFCI receps in the daisy-chain.  And then you have a devil of a time resetting them.  Why didn't the washer knock out this local GFCI recep? (if it is one).  That is why I suspect it's a labeled plain recep.

Comment: @JPhi1618 yep it doesn't have the TEST and RESET button on it; just the sticker of GFCI protected.

Comment: OK, that setup is correct, then.  Can you do the extension-cord trick again, but to an outlet on a circuit that is GFCI protected?  (i.e. either buttons or a sticker).   Must be a full 3-wire extension cord, cheaters will break the test!